# asp.net, razor: how do I retrieve my model after I have made changes to it?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have this pagemodel, which basically inputs the values from my db into the model:

```
 public class Skills : PageModel
    {
        public static string userId = string.Empty; // needs to be static or else value gets lost

        [BindProperty]
        public List<SkillsDisplayModel> cats { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetUserId(string id, string categoryId)
        {
            // gets the url params 
            await GetCategories(categoryId);
            return Page();

        }

        private async Task GetCategories(string categoryId)
        {
       //.. fills the model

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostButton_Submit(IFormCollection data)
        {
            return Page();
        }

    }
```

The model list looks like this:

```
public class SkillsDisplayModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Color backgroundColor = new Color();
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get => backgroundColor;
        set
        {
            backgroundColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    //.. shortend for brevity

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false; 

}
```

and my form looks like this:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-page-handler="Button_Submit">
                    <table class="table-fullWitdh centered" >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="centered">
                                <p>
                                    Bitte markiere alle Fertigkeiten, die dein potentieller Kandidat "Gut" oder "Sehr gut" beherrschen soll
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            @*main content*@
                            <td class="centered" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                                <table class="table-fullWitdh centered" >
                                    @{
                                        int counter = 0;
                                        foreach(var elem in Model.cats)
                                        {
                                            if(counter % 6 == 0)
                                            {
                                                <tr class="centered"></tr>
                                            }
                                            <td class="centered">
                                                 <input type="checkbox" id="@elem.Id" checked="@elem.IsChecked">
                                                 <label for="@elem.Id">@elem.DisplayValue</label>
                                            </td>
                                            counter++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                </table>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                        <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <div class="centered" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                                   <input style="width: 30% !important; opacity: 0.2; " value="Weiter" class="baseButton" type="submit">
                                 </div>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                </form>
```

Now, everyting renders fine. My checkboxes are all there, the labels are all filled with the attributes of the list on the model and even when I click submit the function at the bottom of my controller (page model) page is fired. But there is never a model returned.
If I check on my List it says count = 0.

How can I retrieve my model after post?

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```
<td class="centered">
                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(y => y.cats[i].IsChecked)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.cats[i].DisplayValue)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.cats[i].Id)
                                                <label for="@Model.cats[i].Id">@Model.cats[i].DisplayValue</label>
                                            </td>
```

solves all issues